# console.log() not working and Nodemailer not sending an email when Form data on server is validated and proven to be valid inside of POST

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a form that is supposed to allow a user to enter information and send a suggestion to me for something I should make for my YouTube channel right from my website. However, I have run into an issue where when I'm testing things inside of the POST, `console.log();`won't work and nodemailer won't send a confirmation email to the person submitting the form. Can someone help me with this?

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var validator = require('./config/validator.js');
var mailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
app.get('/feedback', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/form.html'));

app.post('/form', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const formConfig = validator.getFormConfig('suggestions');
  const errorFields = validator.validate(req.body, formConfig);

  if(errorFields.length === 0) {
    let transporter = mailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: '*email*',
        pass: '*emailPassword*'
      }
    });

    let noGenderSelected = 'You did not select your gender.';

    var mailOptions = {
      from: '*email from*',
      to: req.body.email,
      subject: 'Response Recieved',
      text: `Hello ${req.body.fname} ${req.body.lname}!
      We have recieved your response! Thank you for your feedback!

      The data you entered was:

      - First Name: ${req.body.fname}
      - Last Name: ${req.body.lname}
      - Email: ${req.body.email}
      - Country: ${req.body.country}
      - Suggestion: ${req.body.suggestion}
      - Gender: ${req.body.gender ? `${req.body.gender}` : `${noGenderSelected}`}`,
      html: `Hello ${req.body.fname} ${req.body.lname}!
      We have recieved your response! Thank you for your feedback!

      The data you entered was:

      <ul>
      <li>First Name: ${req.body.fname}</li>
      <li>Last Name: ${req.body.lname}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Country: ${req.body.country}</li>
      <li>Suggestion: ${req.body.suggestion}</li>
      <li>Gender: ${req.body.gender ? `${req.body.gender}` : `${noGenderSelected}`}</li>
      </ul>`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        res.send('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
  }

  res.json(errorFields);
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server listening on port 8080'));
```

The GitHub repository is here: https://github.com/Macintoshuser2/JTG-Website/tree/form-page-mods

Comment: a few things that might be worth trying (if you haven't already): 1. make it `console.log('/form body', req.body)`...just in case the body is an empty string or something weird. 2. add a logger middleware `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log('whatever you want to log to check'); next(); })`. 3. debug with chrome or vscode or something, set breakpoints and check stuff. 4. check your form post data in the web browser dev tools network panel.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` not working is a fairly reliable indication that code execution did not reach that point.

This suggests that the route `app.post('/form', (req, res) => {...` is not being taken.

The action attribute of the form in `public/form.html` appears to be documentary. Form data is posted using an AJAX call in the `validateAndSubmit` function declared in `public/validate.js`

The part of code that could explain the problem is this:

```
//...

let formValid = (errorFields.length === 0)
const clientOn = true;
if(clientOn) {
  if(!formValid) {
    markFields(errorFields);
    formValid = true;
  }
}
if(!formValid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(
// ...
```

Here the `if(clientOn`) true branch is taken ( for debugging?) and sets `formValid` true. But the ajax call is only made if `formValid` is false.

`if(!formValid)` could be a typo for `if( formValid)` or perhaps `if(errorFields.length === 0)`

If this really is a typo please consider deleting the post - questions resulting from typos are subject to being closed.

Comment: I got rid of the ! and now I get this error stacktrace in the chrome dev tools: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: Add debugging code. E.G. place the ajax call within a `try` block, add a call to `JSON.stringify(data)` in the `try` block immediately before the ajax call, and call `console.trace` in the `catch(error)` block of the `try/catch` block pair.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the issue was. In the validation code on both client and server, I'm getting the `selectedItem` property of the `paper-dropdown-menu`, which returns a `paper-item` element and AJAX did not like it, nor did the JSON so, I changed it to take the `selectedItemLabel` property of the `paper-dropdown-menu` element and now it's working perfectly.